# iFrame Injection

Tags: javascript, iis, iframe, coldfusion, windows-server-2003

Recently one of my sites have been hit with an iframe injection:

`<iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="http://www.example.com/" width="0" height="1"></iframe>`

It happens at random times and gets inserted in random include files etc.

We have clean scanned all computers for viruses, changed all ftp/remote desktop passwords but the problem still occurs.

Also we have used search programs to find the string 'http://www.example.com/' but to no avail. We have over 100,000 files on the server so is tricky to find the source. In addition to this the server company said they cannot assist us as there is no adware/viruses currently on there!

We are using coldfusion.

Some advice would really be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: check your queries and the portion where you are reading the data from forms

Comment: See here:

http://serverfault.com/questions/416418/code-injection-some-sort-of-hack

Answer (score 0):

Check your database.. It definitely inserted in your text fields table columns through SQL Injection. Stop looking for viruses on your server in fact workaround on your coldfusion pages to avoid sql injection (mostly your public pages like contact us).

Always use  tag in sql.

Comment: The reason we don't think it is a sql injection is the fact that the code is being inserted to include files and template files rather than the db itself. 

Does this rule out an sql injection?

Comment: And where these template/include files created? I mean, does it created through coldfusion or it is written by developer at the time of development? Also make sure if you are providing option to upload document then checking extension of uploaded to avoid suspicious file.

Comment: We created the include files at time of development. We basically have a top and bottom template for our site which includes a few different includes.

Comment: Then look for suspicious code (may be uploaded through) interface. Also is it hosted on shared server?

Comment: We have looked and cannot find any suspicious code. We have 1000's of files including 7 or 8 sites that it now seems to be affecting. It's a dedicated server in which myself and another developer can connect to using remote desktop.